# Условный рендеринг с помощью FlatList

Tags: react-native

У меня есть массив с объектами (пример ниже) и нужно с помощью рендерить на странице, но рендер должен происходить только тех объектов, у которых поле type = 0. Если честно, то не совсем пойму как это сделать внутри самого FlatList (при передаче data или extraData).

```
const SERVICES = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'ServiceFree1',
        description: 'Что-то здесь написано, но что я хз, пусть будет так',
        type: 0, 
        cost: 10000,

    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'ServicePaid1',
        description: 'Что-то здесь написано, но что я хз, пусть будет так',
        type: 1, 
        cost: 10000,
        
    }
]
```

Код FlatList'a

```
<View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList 
                style={{width: '100%'}}
                data={data}
                keyExtractor={( item ) => item.id.toString()}
                renderItem={({item}) => <ServicesItem item={item} navigation={navigation}/>}
            />        
</View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот ответ (передать нужно нужные пропсы)

```
<View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList 
                style={{width: '100%'}}
                data={data.filter(d => d.type === 0)}
                keyExtractor={( item ) => item.id.toString()}
                renderItem={({item}) => <ServicesItem item={item} navigation={navigation}/>}
            />        
</View>
```